# How do I turn a list of lists of words into a sentence string?

Tags: python

I have this list

```
[['obytay'], ['ikeslay'], ['ishay'], ['artway']]
```

where I need it to look like

```
obytay ikeslay ishay artway
```

Can anybody help? I tried using `join` but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have a list in a list so its not working the way you think it should. Your attempt however was absolutely right. Do it as follows:

```
' '.join(word[0] for word in word_list)
```

where word_list is your list shown above.

```
>>> word_list = [['obytay'], ['ikeslay'], ['ishay'], ['artway']]
>>> print ' '.join(word[0] for word in word_list)
obytay ikeslay ishay artway
```

`Tobey likes his wart`

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't understand how it turned into a list into a list. In the coding i created an empty list, then appended those words into it. The list inside the list definitely complicated things for me

Comment: @user3477556, Maybe, it would be better then, to modify your appending part of the code so that you don't end up with this problem in the first place and lead to further complications. Pig Latin huh? :)

Comment: Turns out in the other function that turns the normal words into piglatin, i append the new piglatin word into an empty list also. i fixed it all up and the `join` function works normally :D Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @user3477556, onay roblempay, oodgay ucklay!

Answer (score 4):

It is a list of strings. So, you need to chain the list of strings, with [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) like this

```
from itertools import chain
print " ".join(chain.from_iterable(strings))
# obytay ikeslay ishay artway
```

It will be efficient if we first convert the chained iterable to a list, like this

```
print " ".join(list(chain.from_iterable(strings)))
```

Comment: Downvoter, Please let me know what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but maybe because he/she thought the solution was too complicated. Honestly, I don't know. :P

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `reduce`.

```
l = [['obytay'], ['ikeslay'], ['ishay'], ['artway']]
print " ".join(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, l))
#'obytay ikeslay ishay artway'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def pig_latin(text):
  say = ""
  x=[]

  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()

  for word in words:
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    x.append(word[1:]+word[0]+'ay')

  for eachword in x:
    say += eachword+' '
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  return say
        
print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"

print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```