# How to put together all the words in a string?

Tags: python, for-loop

Using a loop, how can I convert a string in a unique term, where all the words are linked together with '_'?

starting from this:

```
[['Drama'],
 ['Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller'],
 ['Drama'],
 ['Children', 'Drama'],
 ['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller']
```

I would obtain this:

```
[['Drama'],
 ['Drama_Horror_Thriller'],
 ['Drama'],
 ['Children_Drama'],
 ['Comedy_Drama_Horror_Thriller']
```

Comment: You are looking for the `str.join` method. For example `"_".join(["Drama", "Horror", "Thriller")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn a list of lists of words into a sentence string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741526/how-do-i-turn-a-list-of-lists-of-words-into-a-sentence-string)

Comment: You also probably don't want the inner list any more. Weird to have a list with always one element in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` as well, joining every element with `_` using lambda function.

```
l = [['Drama'],
 ['Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller'],
 ['Drama'],
 ['Children', 'Drama'],
 ['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller']]

# map() to join each member with `_`
#if you want it in form [[],[],[]]
test =  list(map(lambda x: ['_'.join(x)] , l)) 
#or if in list ['','','']
#test = list(map(lambda x: '_'.join(x) , l)) 
print(test)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
inp = (
[['Drama'],
 ['Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller'],
 ['Drama'],
 ['Children', 'Drama'],
 ['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller']]
)

print([['_'.join(l)] for l in inp])
```

Comment: `[["_".join(word)] for word in inp]` This would give the exact output needed.

Comment: @domiziano It works. I've added your exact input and gives your exact output.